# I need to put a horizontal boxplot layer on top of a vertical density plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to overlay a horizontal boxplot on a vertical density line?  coord_flip() rotates both both the layers in ggplot2.  I am currently using geom_segment to draw the horizontal boxplot.

Comment: Have a look at the `ggstance` package.

Comment: The `geom_violin` with `draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75)` isn't exactly what you are looking for but will be similar.

Comment: Thanks Axeman.  ggstance was what I needed.